# Double approximation using lexical_cast

Tags: boost, precision, lexical-cast

When I use following line of code

```
std::wcout << boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(5.453) << std::endl;
```

I obtain the following result on the console

```
5.4530000000000003
```

What's be best way to approximate the number in order to obtain the same number that I use for conversion?

Comment: Why the lexical cast? You're already writing to a stream, so just set up formatting the usual way. Or use boost format.

Comment: The code that I use is a bit more complex, and the core of the problem involves the precision with `lexical_cast` conversion to `wstring`, so I've tried to write a simpler example.

Comment: If you have specific formatting requirements, `lexical_cast` is not a good choice. From [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html): " For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of lexical_cast, the conventional std::stringstream approach is recommended." | I would try boost format, e.g. `str(boost::format("%0.3f") % 5.453)`

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at it, thanks.